# Closure Theorem (Shoenfield Mathematematical Logic)

Tags: logic, quantifiers

This theorem states the following : Let **A** be a formula and **A'** be its closure(all the free variables of **A** are quantified in **A'**). Then **A** is provable iff **A'** is provable. I understand that when the closure of the formula contains just existential quantifiers, but why is it true in the case where **A'** contains universal quantifiers?

Comment: This depends terribly on your logic, and it isn't even true in most logics.  Free variables represent universal quantifications over their deductions, not over the formula itself.

Comment: This is a theorem on the book Mathematical Logic by Joseph Shoenfield. The theorem is stated there http://www.cs.ru.nl/bachelorscripties/2015/Emma_Gerritse___4248120___Herbrands_theorem.pdf#theorem.4.14 as in the book (Theorem 3.12).

Comment: @doze: See definition 3.12. The book's concept of "closure" spefically specifies _universal_ quantifiers.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yeah you are right about that, but this makes me even more confused :D. I mean, how i get the implication " provable(**A**) implies provable (**A'**)? in the book this is proved by some application of rules (with the generalization rule too) but i can't understand why this should be true. It seems that they key point is that i can add a universal quantifier to a formula **on a variable that is not free in the formula** to get another formula such that they are logically equivalent. But when it comes to the closure i lose myself in the reasoning.

Comment: See page 31; he has already proved **Generalization rule**: if $\vdash A$, then $\vdash \forall x A$. This licenses the part : if $A$ is provable (i.e. $\vdash A$), then its (universal) *closure* : $\forall x_1 \ldots \forall x_n A$ is.

Comment: The other part needs the **Substitution Th** : $\vdash \forall x_1 \ldots \forall x_n A \to A_{x_1, \ldots x_n} [a_1, \ldots a_n]$. Thus, if $\vdash A'$ (the closure of $A$), then by detachment rule (*modus ponens*) we have : $\vdash A$ (here we use the variable $x_i$ as the term $a_i$).

Comment: So the variable x is not free in **A** ? because it uses the ∀ introduction rule to prove it and that states that x should be not free in the formula. But when it comes to the closure of the formula itself, the variables that you are quantifying on are all free in the original formula

Comment: In your notes (page 7), the (universal) *closure* is **Definition 3.2** and we have also **Rule 3.5** (Generalization rule) and **Theorem 3.11** (Substitution Theorem).

Comment: But you have still to correct the text of your question: "all the free variables of $A$ are **universally** quantified in $A'$".

Comment: I get how the proof of the closure theorem works from the statements of the previous theorem and the application of the rules. What i don't get basically is the generalization Rule and its proof. Because it seems counter-intuitive to me to say that if a formula is provable then its provable for every value you assign to its free variables.

Comment: The **Gen rule** is not $\forall$-intro : $\varphi (x) \vdash \forall x \varphi(x)$, with proviso. But with it, if we have $\vdash \varphi$, we have a derivation of $\varphi$ with **no** assumptions left; thus, there are no *free** vars in open assumptions, and we may apply $\forall$-intro without ado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your statement of the theorem is missing a word. $A'$ should be the *universal* closure of $A$ -- that is, every free variable in $A$ is *unversally* quantified to produce $A'$.

The theorem is **not true** if existential quantifiers can also be used. For example, in a pure predicate calculus (with equality) in a logical language that contains a constant symbol $0$, the formula $x=0$ is not provable, but $\exists x(x=0)$ is.

Comment: This makes me a little more confused. How can i prove that the provability of **A** implies the probability of **A'**. Probably i'm missing something very elementary but for example if i can prove _(x=0)_ why i'm able to prove  this for every _x_?

Comment: @doze: That's impossible to answer as long as you're not revealing which formal system you want to prove that about. (There are many different proof systems for first-order-logic). Most of them, though, have a generalization rule in some shape that you can append to the end of a proof of $A$ in order to yield a proof of $A'$.

Comment: @doze - because you cannot prove $(x=0)$. To say that the formula is *provable* : $\vdash (x=0)$ implies that, by soundness, it is *valid*: $\vDash (x=0)$, and this is not. A simple interpretation with domain $\{ 0, 1 \}$ where we assign to $x$ the valus $1$ will falsify it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Ok now everything is clear, i think i got confused by the new terminology i saw in the book plus i got some lack of understanding of some basic concepts. Now i understood the theorem and the rule, thank to the both of you!